# How could I work around MSVC's limit on the length of mangled names?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, name-mangling

I have a piece of code that heavily uses templates, resulting in really long mangled names (more than 3000 characters long). This is not a problem when building in release mode with MSVC 10 -- probably because everything gets inlined as expected. However, when I try building in debug mode I get linker errors about unresolved external symbols. They can't be external, since they're only instantiated implicitly, so their definition is definitely present in the translation unit.

A curious thing I observed is that while some mangled names appear fully in the error message, others seem to be truncated, with something that looks like a hash value appended at the end. The length of the truncated mangled name and the hash together is 255 characters. I'm assuming this is some trick MSVC is using to speed up linking by limiting name length.

So, is there any reasonable way to resolve this mess?

Comment: The [documented limit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc2y4ddf.aspx) is 2047 chars.  The 255 limit applies to the debugger, might be visible.  Surely just about everybody can think of a reasonable way to stay below 2048: don't do it.

Comment: It's not that easy to avoid when you have a big code base that heavily uses templates.